# Road Maps in Java

Tags: java, google-maps, maps

I'm creating a simple application in Java and I would like to be able to show some points and paths on a map (a road map, not a satellite one). I have been looking for some API that would let me do this, but Google Maps API isn't available for Java and can be only used for web applications, and WorldWind didn't seem to offer road maps and the size of the API was a bit bigger than I would fancy.

Do you know of any API that would meet my needs?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"I'm creating a simple application.."* Simplicity sometimes comes in the look of the GUI & in the saying, rather than the coding.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Is it a web application? An Eclipse one? A Swing one? These details are good to tell when you're looking for suggestions of an API.

Just a few ideas then...

For rendering you'll probably need:

- GEF for Eclipse-based apps;
- Graphics2D for Swing;
- HTML5 for web or static image generator on the server side;

For geocoding look at [GeoTools](http://www.geotools.org).

Might be not as simple as you imagine in the end.

Comment: It uses Swing. Thanks for the tips. I will have a look at it and see if I could use it.

Comment: For Swing there's an API in GeoTools: http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/unsupported/swing/index.html