# Road Maps, Java

Tags: java, google-maps

I'm trying to implement a road map in my desktop Java application.

The idea of my project is so allow the user to place points onto a map where a specific photo was taken.

I was going to use Google maps, but reading the T&C, I noticed it has to be used on the web only. I have managed to implement a map onto some free web hosting (http://jwasley.netii.net) - but it won't display in the Java web browser I created.

Is this the best way of doing it, or is there an API for road maps. I did look into OpenStreetMap but couldn't find any decent tutorials.

Cheers

Comment: possible duplicate of [Road Maps in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400241/road-maps-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using jxmapkit as a Swing framework for displaying maps. It includes powerful features such as overlays. It is part of the swingx project. I believe it supports a number of different mapping repositories including OpenStreetMap.

You can see an example here:

http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/10/30/building-maps-into-swing-app-with-jxmapviewer.html

If you would like to see more then the open source project iphoneanalyzer uses it extensively. The code is available here:

http://iphoneanalyzer.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/iphoneanalyzer/trunk/gui/src/main/java/com/crypticbit/ipa/ui/swing/